# postgres aggreation column rename

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this sql statement on postgres 15.1:

```sql
SELECT
  keyword_id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN month = 1 THEN searches END) AS "Searches: Jan " || year
FROM monthly_searches
WHERE created_at::date >= NOW() - INTERVAL '1 year'
  and keyword_id = '0712e55c-e05e-4215-a43b-caad95b8de8e'
GROUP BY  keyword_id,year
```

note year is a numeric like 2023. I'm getting
syntax error at or near "||"

I've tried a few combinations of queries but still cant seem to understand how I can rename the column to be Searches: Jan 2023, etc for each month

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this alternative approach using the CONCAT operator:

```
SELECT
  keyword_id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN month = 1 THEN searches END) AS CONCAT('Searches: Jan ', CAST(year AS TEXT))
FROM monthly_searches
WHERE created_at::date >= NOW() - INTERVAL '1 year'
  AND keyword_id = '0712e55c-e05e-4215-a43b-caad95b8de8e'
GROUP BY keyword_id, year;
```